# Tools page showing "sort by close votes" while on reopen votes

Tags: bug, 10k-tools, sorting, vote-to-reopen

On 10k moderation tools of stack overflow, there is a tab for "most reopen votes".

You could sort by the original close reasons of the post. Or by the number of "reopen votes".

But for some reason, to sort by the number of "reopen votes", it shows "sort by close votes" instead. But it should be written as "sort by reopen votes" instead.

Screenshot:

[image]

On the top right, it reads "sort by close votes".

Where it should read "sort by reopen votes".

Screenshot if I click on it:

[image]

The numbers are right, they show the correct number of reopen votes. The first post there:

[Representing reverse web links graph in Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70279524/representing-reverse-web-links-graph-in-scheme)

Does have 2 pending reopen votes.

---

So it is a bug, it should be "sort by reopen votes".

Comment: Valid also for "Recently Reopened" section under "Recent occurrences".